# Session vars problem php

Tags: php, session

Well I have unexpected situation here. I am using a code form a site I made long time ago and it works there.

I have 3 pages:
- news.php
- newscheck.php
- newsadd.php

I have `session_start()` on every page. In newscheck.php, I generate `session_vars` for the fields and `echo` them in the same page so the user to check the info. And they are OK. Clicking on resume takes the user to newsadd.php where the info goes to the database but there all session vars are empty.

The most interesting is that I have `session_var` generate back in the login page and it is OK in all pages but the generated vars in newscheck.php are gone in the next page.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: @VolkerK: Did you read the question?

Comment: I've had more sense out of a lolcat snap. You really need to rewrite this dude before anyone has a  chance to grasp your problem. And accepting previous answers you have will stop scaring people off.

Comment: @Victor accept some answers to your previous questions. You'll earn reputation and it'll be more likely your questions will be taken seriously.

Comment: @Glycerine, I have edited it and removed the profanity.

Comment: I am sorry if my question is not asked properly or didn't accept answers. I don't know how the system works here. Juts I am too nervous about this stupid problem.

Comment: @Victor: Check out the FAQ at http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask - you have the start of how to ask a question down pat, but you need to read about accepting answers or people will just stop answering your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have put the `session_start()` function in **very beginning of the newsadd.php** and there are no "headers already sent" warnings on that page.